# Login in React.js with localStorage token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux

Im developing a Login system of a React WebSite. We're using api_tokens for access to the API and retrieve the info as validate user credentials. I need to restringe everything when the auth fails and redirect to the user login page, currently Im using redux as app global state. The issue is I'm saving the api_token in browser localStorage, and I need to dispatch the UNAUTH_USER when the api_token is modified by Browser Clear History or other things........

I was wondering if I can attach some eventListener to that... and if is the right solution..

The code looks below:

```
import React from 'react'

import Header from './Header'
import Navigation from '../navigation/components/Navigation'
import Ribbon from '../ribbon/Ribbon'
import Footer from './Footer'
import Shortcut from '../navigation/components/Shortcut'

import LayoutSwitcher from '../layout/components/LayoutSwitcher'

import {connect} from 'react-redux'

// require('../../smartadmin/components/less/components.less');

class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

componentWillMount() {

  if(!this.props.authenticated) {
    this.props.router.push('/login');
  }
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {

  if(!nextProps.authenticated) {
    this.props.router.push('/login');
  }
}

render() {  
  if (!this.props.authenticated) {
    this.props.router.push('/login');
    return null;
  }
  else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Navigation />
        <div id="main" role="main">
          <LayoutSwitcher />
          <Ribbon />

          {this.props.children}
        </div>

        <Footer />
        <Shortcut />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      authenticated: state.auth.authenticated
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

Comment: You can take a look at this demo https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react

Comment: Yes I see! Thanks. Very helpful.

Comment: You might want to consider your token validity directly in your request helper and redirect your user if you get a 401 status. Here is an example https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-helper-plugin/lib/src/utils/request.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same thing in my app. For every call my Sagas make, if an api error occurs and a 403 expired/unvalid token is raised, I dispatch there a redux action that clears localstorage and disconnect the user (I have a refresh token mechanism retry before that).

I'm not sure that you can attach an eventListener to a localStorage expiration, but placing a check at your API calls mechanism would be IMO a good practice.

Best

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm handling ideas.

Comment: What we do is whenever a component is loaded and if authentication is to be checked then first we check for valid token and then let the user access the page.

Comment: yes, I understand but that implies do an api request to the backend in every route url change, I can't figure out if that can decrease site performance.

Comment: @ReinierCésarMujicaHernández that's not what I'm doing. I'm doing my calls no matter what, but automatically catch "session expired" errors, then refresh my token (if I can) and the re-play the previous call; No overhead that way.